# Controller unable to extend class

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm getting a nullPointerException with the constructor below... I've also included the parent class.

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentController' defined in file [C:\Users\bkuhl\JavaProjects\cmt\cmt\target\cmt\WEB-INF\classes\com\site\cmt\web\ContentController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.fettergroup.cmt.web.ContentController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And the class (constructor was left out so that it would use the parent constructor)

```
public class ContentController extends com.site.cmt.library.Controller {
     ...
}
```

and the parent class

```
public class Controller {
    private SortedMap<Integer, String> cssFiles;
    private SortedMap<Integer, String> jsFiles;

    public Controller () {
        this.addCss("global.css");
        this.addJs("global.js");
    }
    ....
```

Comment: I am suspecting something going wrong in the addCss and addJs methods. Could you please put the complete code of the Controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried ommit  `addCss` and `addJs` to be sure that problem is not inside of implementation method?